# How to prevent all writes to disk from within python

Tags: python

When doing automated tests, I like to make sure my script does not write any data to the disk. I am doing tests on the script as a whole, not unit tests of individual functions.

**Is there a way to intercept all Disk-IO that a python script performs from within this script?**

Obviously, I can mock the open function (e.g. with  the mock package http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/helpers.html?#mock-open ) but the problem is that I need to know in what module the open happens. I have to mock `__main__.open` as well as `__module1.open` and `module2.open` and so on.
The problem is that I do not know what modules will write to files.

Comment: Your previous revision was just fine and probably more precise.

Comment: I'm speculating but if you are running on a *nix machine I think you are able to redirect I/O so it will not write to disk. I would go this way so I wouldn't have to touch the application code in case you want to be able to have I/O again for another execution.

Comment: @Marcs Redirection only works if the script is writing to standard output (or more generally, to open files inherited from its caller); the caller has no control over files the script opens explicitly.

Comment: Maybe a script that would simply link the destination folder of the app to a [tmpfs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tmpfs), if there is enough RAM to spare. Wouldn't block the writes, would just write to RAM instead of HDD/SDD. For sure no IO to disk though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If mocking `open` is enough, you can stick the mock into the [`builtins` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/builtins.html); this is the module that is consulted for all built-in functions:

```
with mock.patch('builtins.open', mock_open()):
    # ...
```

In Python 2, the module was called [`__builtin__`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/__builtin__.html).

Note that this doesn't necessarily catch all writes; anything that uses `os.open()` to use OS filehandles directly or uses `io.open()` or `codecs.open()` could still end up writing to disk.